# How to create a class that already exists on the window

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to create a class called `Text`, but I get the error.

> Duplicate identifier 'Text'

```
class Text extends MyOtherClass {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This is already a JavaScript class that exists on the `Window`. I believe I can add it to another object but I don't know if this is the best practice.

What options do I have so I can use `Text` or `Object` or any other item that is already defined on the window?

I was thinking maybe I could use a `namespace`, but I am not sure if that works or not, or if it works that way that I would like. I am running the final code in the browser, and it doesn't support modules, so I don't want to do a module path which I think namespaces do.

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    class Text extends MyOtherClass {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

When I attempt to call it like this:

```
myFunction(MyNamespace.Text);
```

I get this error:

> Property 'Text' does not exist on type 'typeof MyNamespace'

Comment: You'd need a `/// <reference` comment at the top of the file in which you're calling `myFunction(MyNamespace.Text)`, I believe, since namespaces are used with what TS calls ["internal modules"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md).

Comment: I have a `tsconfig.json` which has that information

Comment: That says you need to use an `import` and not a `reference tag`

Comment: For a module, yes, not a namespace. It's confusing, no doubt. All I can speak from is my experience, and I've found that putting the comment gets rid of the error. You may have a different experience.

Comment: Okay so it looks like I have to export the class within the namespace.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes that's correct. Types are not accessible outside their parent `namespace` declaration unless they are have been exported. This applies to interfaces, classes, and type aliases.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't think that the triple-slash directive would've been a solution. The error message indicates that it's aware of the namespace but can't find the type you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a namespaced type outside of its parent namespace declaration it must be `export`ed from the namespace. If it is not exported, it will *not* be available outside of its parent `namespace` declaration. This applies *even* if you're using identical namespaces.

Here's an example:

```
namespace Example {
    class Search {
        searchKey = document.getElementById('');
    }
    export class OtherSearch {

    }
    type Primary = '123';
    export type Secondary = '123';

}

Example.OtherSearch; // No Error
Example.Search; // Compile Error

namespace Example {
  class SecondSearch {
    // Compile error: Example.Primary is not visible even though its the same namespace.
    alpha() : Example.Primary {

    }
    beta(): Example.Secondary {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your intention was to create a class `Text` and consume it without touching the global `Text`, the answer depends on whether you're splitting up your code into small modules (aka "external modules" which I strongly recommend) or whether all your code lives inside the same file ("internal modules" or `namespace`s).

## External module

Suppose you define your class `Text` in `fileA.ts`:

```
export class Text {
  // class implementation goes here
}
// Other classes, variables etc
```

then in your consuming file `fileB.ts` (assumed to be in the same folder for simplicity), `import` the `Text` class

```
import {Text} from './fileA'

// Use Text normally
var a = new Text();
```

In `fileB.ts`, `Text` will be the user-defined one instead of the global `Text`.

## Internal modules

In the same file `fileA.ts`:

```
namespace SomeName {
  export class Text {
    // Implementation
  }
}

var a = new SomeName.Text();
```

If on the other handyou want to modify the global `Text` type itself, which you shouldn't do unless for a good reason, you can add new properties/methods to `Text` by

```
declare global {
  interface Text {
    // New stuff goes here
  }
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules) for more details. This requires TypeScript 1.8 and above.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. Types declared within a namespace must be exported as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use namespace if you want to create class with same name. But then you would have to call it as namespace.class. It would work. You cannot create same class more than once in same namespace.

Comment: When I do that, I get the error `Property 'Text' does not exist on type 'typeof MyNamespace'`